# In C#, how to hand off a value copy of a resource for my threads to use

Tags: c#, multithreading

Within the structure of my app, each thread makes their own instance of `bigSlowObject` which is slow to instantiate.

**Edit: This object comes from a .dll and is sealed and cannot be modified**

The threads then sets a few properties (the `bigSlowObjectID`  and `hostName` properties) and commits it (Which is very fast) and then exits.  The class looks something like this.

```
public class bigSlowObject{

    public guid bigSlowObjectID {get;set;} 
    public string hostName {get;set;}     
    
    public bigSlowObject(){
        //build object, which is the slow part
    }
}
```

Seems inefficient to keep newing basically identical objects just to change two fields.  To remedy this, I then tried making my code build an initial instance of `bigSlowObject` in the `Main()` method, called `baseBigSlowObject`.  I then had my threads try to make their own copy of it, to skip that big build cost.

However, I kept getting errors of `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

I tried unboxing the object like so, which I thought would make my thread convert a reference type to a value type:

```
//within the thread
object myBigSlowObject = baseBigSlowObject;
```

But I still run into the same `object reference not set to an instance of an object` error.

Is there something special I need to do so each thread can safely lock for a few nanoseconds to make its own copy of this object then continue?

In an ideal solution each thread would try to get a lock on the `baseBigSlowObject` then make its own copy to continue on with.  Hopefully it would wait if needed for its brother's if one of the other threads has a lock.

Comment: What do you mean by "create a copy"? this statement: `object myBigSlowObject = baseBigSlowObject;` simply assigns a reference so they're pointing to the same object and there's no copying happening here (or more correctly, only the address is being copied). With regards to NPE (object reference not set to an instance of an object), with the small amount of code you've shown here, it's really hard to tell but I imagine your `baseBigSlowObject` is null and therefore the reference to it throws this exception.

Comment: I would also recommend having a look at `Object Pooling` which seems to be quite ideal for your problem. The idea is that you create a few of these expensive to create objects in the beginning and keep reusing them.

Comment: Instantiating new classes is not that slow C#. If the constructor of `bigSlowObject` is the problem, why not store the results of the constructor in a class or struct? Then, you can give each new `bigSlowObject` access to that data structure instead of having each one run the expensive constructor.

Comment: The class I'm using comes from a third party DLL I cannot modify and it does some internal goodness which is slow @PatrickTucci

Answer (score 1):

The `Lazy<T>` class is intended for this purpose. You won't be able to reference an instance until it's ready, and all callers get the same instance. This should do the trick:

```
    public static Lazy<bigSlowObject> theObject = new Lazy<bigSlowObject>();
```

to reference the object, use the `Value` property:

```
    theObject.Value.bigSlowObjectId
```

Comment: This looks promising however I cannot edit the base class.  I edited that into my question.

Comment: The Lazy singleton doesn't need to be in the base class, it can be a public static member of any class. Construction of the `bigSlowObject` instance will be triggered on the first access of the `Value` property.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, hope I got you right and it will help:

Did you try to clone the object class?

```
public class bigSlowObject : ICloneable
{
    public guid bigSlowObjectID {get;set;} 
    public string hostName {get;set;}     

    public bigSlowObject(){
        //build object, which is the slow part
    }

    public object Clone()
    {
       return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

and then:

```
bigSlowObject myObjectFromMainThread = new bigSlowObject();
bigSlowObject myObjectFromSecondThread = myObjectFromMainThread.Clone();
```

Comment: This seems so promising but I cannot edit the base class as it is sealed.